# Redis Multitenency with master/slave structure?

Tags: database, redis, multi-tenant

I am new in  multitenancy concept.

I am confused about some stuff.

Is there any correlation redis master/slave structure and multitenancy?

can we use master/slave structure to multitenant redis?

If not related, how can we implement multitenancy for redis?
is there any sample?

Comment: What multitenancy do you want? Complete separation? Why not just launch an instance for every tenant?

Comment: yes I want Complate separation.  Ok lets suppose I create an instance for each tenant, but I don't know how to redirect incoming tenant request to related redis instance with this tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using multiple Redis instances. Ideally it would be a master-slave pair for each tenant. You can route requests either on application level, or via TCP proxy (for example `HAProxy`).

If you want to save resources you can use one instance for many tenants by using command [SELECT](https://redis.io/commands/select). You can set amount of available databases in config file (default is `databases 16`).

Comment: should I seperate redis instances with port. like  : `host:8091 (instance 1)` `host:8092(instance 2)`  `host:8093(instance 3)`  And I tought that  store these in a map on application with related tenancy like this: `(host:8091 - tenancy1_Id)` `(host:8092 - tenancy2_Id)` ...   Than redirect incoming tenant request by tenantId from map. Can I use this way to achieve redirection?

Comment: @sam sure, but `tenancy1_Id` would be the key and `host:8091` would be the value. Be sure to not stuff one server with too much instances. I'd recommend to have 2 cores per instance or at least one. But you'll probably be bound by network with this setup.